# Regex Grab Only First Occurrence of IP from Syslog

Tags: regex, syslog, opennms

I need to put a RegEX into an OpenNMS config file. I am trying to grab just the first IP address from a syslog message. The format is:

```
Sep 13 08:36:37 192.168.75.254 %ASA-4-106023: Deny tcp src outside:144.5.5.255/
56607 dst inside:192.168.75.102/23 by access-group "outside_access_in" [0x0, 0x0]
```

So far I have:

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Which will grab all three of the IP addresses. How do I limit it to one?

In the NMS config file I need to fill in these lines:

```
forwarding-regexp="regex here"
matching-group-host="2"
matching-group-message="3"
```

So I need a regex that will put just the first IP into a group, while creating a group for the entire Syslog message

Comment: What if you use it like `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})[\s\S]*` and grab Group 1 value?

Comment: I tried it, looks like its grabbing everything but group one

Comment: ahhh I see what its doing. Sorry really new to this

Comment: So If I use that and set the expression grabber to "group 1" That should do it right

Comment: I think yes. Try and let know.

Comment: I think that does it. It says the right IP is group 1. But I also need to match the message. How do I get that in a group as well?

Comment: Could you please explain what you need to get in the output? Update the question, too.

Comment: yes I will edit my question above

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/heEsKD/1 - Group 1 is the IP, Group 2 is the host??? Group 3 is the message?

Comment: That look really close. How do I get the message group to capture everything. The whole message?

Comment: What is the message? I already showed how to match everything - `[\s\S]*`

Comment: The entire Syslog. I think I figured it out. I just changed a couple parts of what you sent and I think I have it now

Comment: Yeah, but others won't get it. Please add the expected results to the question.

Comment: Ok, thank you again: Here is what I finished with `(\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s*([\s\S]*)\s*(?=\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|$))`      it grabs everything except initial timestamp which is ok for my need

Comment: haha no problem.

Comment: Have a very nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want

```
\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s*([\s\S]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4RvIir/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})` - Group 1:

  - `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
  - `(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}` - 3 occurrences of a dot and then 1 to 3 digits (`\d{3}`)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([\s\S]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars as many as possible (`*` is a greedy quantifier).

Comment: Very glad to help. If you need more assistance with this pattern, just drop a line here.